# Datastax cassandra connector for spark failing loudly and incomprehensibly

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

My spark-streaming application has the following lines:

I'm attempting to write a series of objects to tables in cassandra (as well as to a text file).  I have the following code:

```scala
val rmqReceiver = new RMQReceiver(queueIp, "vehicle-data")
val statusMessageStream = myStreamingContext.receiverStream[String](rmqReceiver)
val vsStream = customReceiverStream.map(jsonToVehicleStatus)

customReceiverStream.foreachRDD((vs: RDD[String])=> vs.saveAsTextFile("/var/log") )
vsStream.foreachRDD((vs: RDD[Vehicle_Status])=> vs.saveToCassandra("vehicle_data","vehicles",AllColumns) )
vsStream.foreachRDD((vs: RDD[Vehicle_Status])=> vs.saveToCassandra("vehicle_data","vehicle_locations",AllColumns) )
```

I've tried a bunch of variations, but here's what happens:

The text file gets written (sometimes)

The first call "saveToCassandra", successfully saves the record
The second call throws the below listed exception?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, I'm just not seeing what it is.

> java.io.IOException: Failed to prepare statement INSERT INTO "vehicle_data"."vehicle_locations" ("timestamp", "vehicle_id", "lon", "geobin", "lat") VALUES (:"timestamp", :"vehicle_id", :"lon", :"geobin", :"lat"): All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.com$datastax$spark$connector$writer$TableWriter$$prepareStatement(TableWriter.scala:96)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:122)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:120)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:100)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:99)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:151)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:99)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:120)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:84)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:289)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:91)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:33)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.prepare(Unknown Source)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.PreparedStatementCache$.prepareStatement(PreparedStatementCache.scala:45)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:28)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.prepare(Unknown Source)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.com$datastax$spark$connector$writer$TableWriter$$prepareStatement(TableWriter.scala:92)
>       ... 15 more
>   Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:107)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.execute(SessionManager.java:538)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.prepareAsync(SessionManager.java:124)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepareAsync(AbstractSession.java:103)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:89)
>       ... 24 more

additionally, this exception:

> ERROR QueryExecutor: Failed to execute: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBoundStatement@4892f8c2
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /52.{MYIP}:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/52.{MYIP}:9042] Connection has been closed))
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:107)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$1.run(RequestHandler.java:210)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I've hooked this up to a well-rpovisioned cluster, and I"m getting these errors whil trying to exceed 6 writes/second (3 to each table)

Comment: This is probably happening because all of your cassandra hosts were marked down.   What version of spark-cassandra-connector are you running, and you see anything further up in the logs about hosts being marked down or queries timing out?

Comment: ah yes, I've been wondering about that additional exception.

I've updated the question

Comment: I'm running:

 libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.10" % "1.2.0-rc3"

Comment: against spark-core and spark-streaming 1.2.2

Comment: 1.2.0-rc3 uses datastax java-driver 2.1.5 (which is the latest version).  I bet that what is happening is that you have requests to cassandra that are timing out without a response from cassandra, when this happens the java-driver marks the node as down until it can re-establish connection (typically pretty quick).   Are you configuring "spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms" in your SparkConf to some value other then the default?  Also are you configuring the timeouts differently then default in cassandra.yaml on your cassandra nodes?

Comment: It could also be that you are putting enough pressure on your cassandra cluster such that it starts marking hosts as down / is responding slowly.  Any indication of performance issues from the cassandra side?

Comment: I hadn't considered that the timeout value might be so small that it's getting hit.  I just checked and realized that I'm running on a t2.small

Comment: I haven't altered the timeouts at all

Comment: cassandra will typically send Read or Write timeouts after 5 and 2 seconds respectively (with defaults), if it doesn't that could indicate that cassandra is overwhelmed.  If that happens and no response is received within 12 seconds (the default read timeout), the datastax driver assumes the host is down and marks it down (that behavior is changing in 2.1.6/2.0.10 to no longer do this).  I think that might be what you are seeing here.   Depending on your workload/number of nodes/etc. a t2.small might be too small and your instance(s) are so backed up that they cannot respond quickly enough.

Comment: I provisioned a much larger system, and I'm getting the same problems

Comment: messing with the timeouts hasn't helped either, expanded them both to 12 seconds

Comment: this system needs to support a much larger workload anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this on your local machine then check your keyspace's replication factor, make it 1 and try again. This solved for me